# Where can I find PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, pear

I have Selenium IDE/RC, and PHPUnit 3.5 (PEAR) installed, but I can't seem to find PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.  When I type `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium`, I get the following error:

> phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium is already
>   installed and is the same as the
>   released version 1.0.0
>   install failed

It appears that PHPUnit 3.5 *should* come with SeleniumTestCase, but there appears to be some kind of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:

1. Uninstalled PHPUnit
2. Uninstalled Testing_Selenium-0.4.4
3. Attempted to install PHPUnit_Selenium, but failed saying it was already installed
4. Uninstalled PHPUnit_Selenium
5. Reinstalled PHPUnit which came with Selenium

It appears that there was a dependency that was removed physically, but still marked down as installed.  It would not uninstall initially because PHPUnit lists it as a dependency.  Uninstalling PHPUnit, then uninstalling PHPUnit_Selenium directly, allowed me to reinstall PHPUnit, which resolved this issue.